# MariaDB / MySQL CTE Raw SQL ambiguous error

Tags: sql, mariadb, common-table-expression

I have this RAWSQL query

```
with 
    group as (
     select * from groups where id = ?
    ),
    attributes as (
     select JSON_ARRAYAGG(
     JSON_OBJECT('id', a.id,'name', a.name ))
     from attributes a
     join groups g on g.id = ?
     join attribute_group ag on ag.group_id = g.id
     and ag.attribute_id = a.id
    ),
    templates as (
     select JSON_ARRAYAGG(
     JSON_OBJECT('id', t.id,'name', t.name))
     from templates t
     join groups g on g.id = ?
     join group_template gt on gt.group_id = g.id
     and gt.template_id = t.id
    )

    select *, 
    (select cast(count(*) as char) from attribute_group where group_id = ? ) groups_count,
    (select * from groups) groups,
    (select cast(count(*) as char) from group_template where group_id = ? ) templates_count,
    from group
```

I have this error

```
Query 1 ERROR: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'group as (
```

Comment: CTEs are not available prior to mysql 8 - select version() and publish the outcome ( a thing you should always do when raising a question. Also publish the error message in full (including the code)

Comment: What does `SELECT VERSION()` return for you? CTE syntax might not be supported on your instance of MariaDB. Also note that MariaDB is not MySQL, and you should not expect them to be compatible.

Comment: It worked for me in another part of the project

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/keywords.html#keywords-8-0-detailed-G) advises to not use reserved words like **group** and **groups**. They are reserved characters and should only be used for things like the `GROUP BY` statement:

> GROUP (R)
>
> GROUPING (R); added in 8.0.1 (reserved)
>
> GROUPS (R); added in 8.0.2 (reserved)

Outside of that, I noticed a few syntax errors:

1. If you have a table named `GROUP`, which it looks like you do, you
   can escape the reserved word by using back ticks `` or double quotes "" (I.e. `group`, "group").
2. Remove the comma `,` after `templates_count,`.
3. Replace `?` with a valid `id` column value (I used `1` below).

Like so:

```
with 
    `group` as (
     select * from `groups` where id = 1
    ),
    attributes as (
     select JSON_ARRAYAGG(
     JSON_OBJECT('id', a.id,'name', a.name ))
     from attributes a
     join `groups` g on g.id = 1
     join attribute_group ag on ag.group_id = g.id
     and ag.attribute_id = a.id
    ),
    templates as (
     select JSON_ARRAYAGG(
     JSON_OBJECT('id', t.id,'name', t.name))
     from templates t
     join `groups` g on g.id = 1
     join group_template gt on gt.group_id = g.id
     and gt.template_id = t.id
    )

    select *, 
    (select cast(count(*) as char) from attribute_group where group_id = 1 ) groups_count,
    (select * from `groups`)  `groups`,
    (select cast(count(*) as char) from group_template where group_id = 1 ) templates_count
    from `group`
```

Comment: It does not work , same err

Comment: Sorry, updated my answer. You tried backticks and double quotes?

Comment: Can you provide a sample data table so that we can try and reproduce the issue?

Comment: ihave used gro instead of groups , but no luck

Comment: I’ve updated my answer once again. Can you try running the query I’ve attached (changing the id = 1 to a value that exists for id)?

Comment: upvote for mentioning that group is a reserved word